# Не отображается ProgressBar

Tags: android, потоки-данных, java, progress-bar

Есть операция, которая вычисляется довольно долгое время, и порой становиться не совсем понятно работает ли приложение или нет?! Да и хотелось бы видеть на какой стадии находиться. Когда в методе `onCreate()` выполняю `progressBar.progress` (значение), то ничего не происходить, индикатор появляется уже полностью заполненный на конце выполнения задачи, а до этого момента пустота...

Я так понимаю его необходимо вынести в другой поток?! Может есть у кого какие мысли или примеры, буду признателен.

Comment: Есть ещё AsyncTask. Возможно, в Вашем случае это будет самый простой способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень много хорошый примеров в интернете. **[Вот один](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)** из них

```
/**
 * Скачать что то в фоне 
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом скачивание показываем Progress Bar Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Скачиваем файл в потоке
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // ТУТ публикуем статус для progress bar ....
                // Нужно вызвать onProgressUpdate 
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // сохраняем файл
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // закрываем
            output.flush();

            // закрываем streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }     
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * ТУТ произходит обновление progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // Ставим значение в процентах
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * Тут заканчивается поток. И нужно закрыть progress bar (или dialog)
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // удаляем dialog 
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        // Можеи показать рисунок который скачали, ну если этот пример нужен
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }
}
```

в примере показано как управляет c progress bar при скачивании рисунка

Answer (score -1):

Да, нужен отдельный поток.
[threading Example in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722974/threading-example-in-android) - не ручаюсь за работоспособность, но, думаю, что-нибудь подойдёт.
Ещё можете сами погуглить "java android thread" - помогает очень хорошо.