# Android: пауза во время работы без замораживания Activity

Tags: java, android

Есть задача: в активити поочерёдно выводятся новости с каким-то интервалом времени. При этом нужно сделать так, чтобы сам активити не останавливался, поэтому Sleep и подобные методы здесь вряд ли подойдут.

```
do {
    /* 
    Берутся данные из БД 
    */

    // Создаётся экземпляр класса, в котором хранятся все данные, 
    // которые потом добавляются в активити
    DisplayArticleHandler displayArticleHandler = 
    new DisplayArticleHandler(title, content, date, author, org, images);

    //Данные добавляются в активити
    displayArticleHandler.showArticleLayout();

    /*
    Здесь нужно сделать паузу
    */

    // Активити очищается от данных
    displayArticleHandler.clearArticleLayout();
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

И ещё, дополнительный вопрос. Как лучше организовать процесс, чтобы при прочтении последней записи курсор начинал читать значения с начала? Останавливать процесс нужно только если активити станет неактивным.

Comment: используйте `AsyncTask`

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону CursorLoader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь таймером:

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;

private void doSomethingWithDelayAndRepeat()
{
    //берём данные из БД
    //кладём их в курсор
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if(/*проверяем, что записей в курсоре дальше нет*/)
                    {
                        //переключаем курсор в начало
                    }
                    //отображаем данные из курсора
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
}
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Есть такой вариант:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

...

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
         // действие будет выполнено через 2с
     } 
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `AsyncTask`. Тут есть очень много примеров.

попробуте прочитать эти решения :

1. [Библиотека для отображения данных из sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479438/182317)
2. [Не отображается ProgressBar - AsyncTask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474756/182317)
3. [Постоянная работа Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448357/182317)